# Key-Value Store: Overcoming key length limit

Tags: memcached, couchbase, nosql

How do I enforce a unique constraint in Key-Value store where the unique data is longer than the key length limit?

I currently use CouchBase to store the document below:

```
{
    url: "http://google.com",
    siteName: "google.com",
    data:
    {
       //more properties
    }
}
```

Unique constraint is defined at *url* + *siteName*. I however can't use those properties as the key since the length can be longer than the key length limit of CouchBase.

I currently have two solutions in mind but I think that both are not good enough.

---

**Solution 1**
Document key is the SHA1 hash of *url* + *siteName*.

- Advantages: easy to implement
- Disadvantages: collisions can occur

---

**Solution 2**
Document key is the hash(*url* + *siteName*) + *index*.
This is same as Solution 1 but key includes *index* in-case a collision occurs.

To add a document, the application server:

1. set *index* to 0
2. Store document with the key = hash(*url* + *siteName*) + *index*
3. If duplicate key conflict occurred, read document back
4. Does existing document have same *url* and *sitename* with the one we are storing?
5. If yes, throw an exception is duplicates aren't allowed
6. If no, increment *index* and go back to step 2

*This is currently my favorite solution because it can handle collisions*

I a NoSQL n00b! How can I enforce unique constraints in a Key-Value store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading your question, here are my thoughts/opinions, which I think should help give rationale for choosing your first option.

1. Couchbase is an in-memory cache/dictionary. To store many (read "very large incomprehensible number") values, it requires both RAM and disk space. Regardless of how much space each document occupies, all of the document keys are stored in RAM. If you were therefore permitted to store an arbitrarily large value for the key, your server farm would consume RAM faster than you could supply it, and your design would fall apart.
2. With item #1 being the case, your application needs to be designed such that key sizes are as small as practicable.  Dictionary key/hash value computation is up to application API (in the same way that this is left to the .Net or Java API - which likewise compute hashes on the string inputs). The same method to produce a hash should be used regardless of input, for the sake of consistency.
3. The SHA1 has has an extremely low collision probability, and it is designed that way to make "breaking" of the encryption computationally infeasible. This is the foundation behind the "fingerprint" in bitcoins. See [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20110725085124/http://bitcache.org/faq/hash-collision-probabilities) and [here](http://preshing.com/20110504/hash-collision-probabilities/) for tasty reading on the topic.
4. Given what I know about hashes, and given the fact that URLs always start with the same set of characters, this theoretically lowers the likelihood of collision even further.
5. If you are, in fact, storing enough documents that the odds of a SHA1 collision are significant, then there are almost certainly at least a dozen other issues that will affect your application's usability and reliability in a more significant way, and you should devote your energy to thinking about those things.

The hard part about being an engineer is recognizing the need to take a step back from the engineering and say when "good" is "good enough." That being said, option 1 looks like the best choice, it's simple and consistent. If properly applied, that's all you need. Check the box on this one and move on to your next issue.

Comment: I was thinking of using SHA1 too! but I added an index (solution 2: SHA1 + index) because I don't like taking chances (collisions) which is a reflection of my personality. Solution 1 should good enough :)

Comment: Well explained.

Answer (score 1):

I’d go for solution 1 however for choosing the hashing function you should consider the following things:

1. how many data you have? => how large should be the generated hash in order to reduce the probability of colisions to a minimum? - here the best might be SHA-512 which has 512 bits large output hash, compared to the 160 bits from SHA-1
2. what performance do you need from the hashing function? SHA-x are pretty slow compared to md5 and depending on the number of items you want to store md5 could be pretty good as well.

in the end you can also have a combination, use sitename+url as a key if it is short enough, switch to sitename+hash(url) in case this combination can be short enough and in the end only hash both together.

on a related note I’ve found also this question http://www.couchbase.com/communities/q-and-a/key-size-limits-couchbasemembase-again where one answer suggests to compress the keys if it is possible for you.

You could actually use normal gzip compression and encode the text. I’m not sure how well this would work on your usecase, you’ll have to check it, but I used it for JSON files and managed to reduce it down to ~20% - however it was a huge 8MB file so the compression possibilities for your key might be much lower.

Comment: Probably would be quicker and just as applicable to use a hash rather than GZip. Certainly less processor intensive.